# com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured Getting Response code : 400 for PUT Request

Tags: api, rest-assured

```
import static com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import com.jayway.restassured.builder.RequestSpecBuilder;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;
import com.jayway.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class PUTAPI {

public void addNewObject() throws Throwable {
        //Creating api body 
        String xmlBody ="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                +"<PlanRunRequest>"
                +"<PlannedRunName>LIMS_Plan_Run_001</PlannedRunName>"
                +"<Assay></Assay>"
                +"<ReportingTemplate>LIMS_Report1</ReportingTemplate>"
                +"<TubeLabel>tube2343</TubeLabel>"
                +"<TemplateKitBarcode>91A18930101212-1234567171603172100001301</TemplateKitBarcode>"
                +"<PlanRunNotes>This is my 1st Plan</PlanRunNotes>"
                +"<LibraryPrepIDs>"
                +"<LibraryPrepID specimenID=\"\">1004</LibraryPrepID>"
                +"</LibraryPrepIDs>"
                +"</PlanRunRequest>";
        System.out.println(xmlBody);
        //Specifying request body details
        RequestSpecBuilder builder = new RequestSpecBuilder().setContentType("application/xml");
        RequestSpecification requestSpec = builder.build();
        requestSpec.baseUri("http://10.88.195.88").basePath("/ir/lims/create-library-batch").contentType("application/xml");

        //Making post request with authentication
        Response response =given().body(xmlBody).header("username","Auto1Admin").header("password", "ion123").spec(requestSpec).when().put();

        System.out.println("ir"+response.body().asString());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusCode() );

    }

    public static void main (String [] args) throws Throwable {
        PUTAPI service = new PUTAPI();
        service.addNewObject();

    }
}
```

Verified 'String xmlBody' i.e. XML request body with XML-validator, No error found. Verified the request URI, body and headers by submitting this query through postman. It shows me success response code 200 k, But when i run the above script which has correct URI, body and headers its showing response code 400 - bad request.Please help me sort out this issue.

Comment: I issued *http://10.88.195.88/ir/lims/create-library-batch?wsdl* and the page timed out. When the site is up, try issuing the same command from SoapUI or POSTMAN.  First validate that the headers and body are correct then repeat under rest-assured.

Comment: I think there is some problem with rest assured libraries,i have validated these headers and body with postman it works fine.  i tried with same scenario with httpClient library it worked for me.

Comment: @Prabhu Kalshetti Try Logging your request in the Rest Assured. RestAssured is similar to other clients like Postman/SoapUI.